# Insert an element between and its DOM child and its DOM grandson in the stacking context

Tags: html, css, z-index

How can I insert an element between and its child and its grandson?
I have a markup like this:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="img-container">
        <img id="img">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the styles are:

```
#main {
    margin-top: 300px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#img-container {
    margin-top: -150px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
#img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Now the order must be

1. img-container
2. main
3. img

How it works now:
[image: Wrong]

How it is expected to work:
[image: Right]

(Thanks to @ralph.m for images)

Comment: `z-index` property will work efficiently with elements in the same level of the DOM tree

Comment: You wanna use Javascript for this right?

Comment: Include some reasoning or the scope of what or why you're trying to do that.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Comment: @VincentG Thank you, captain obvious!

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I would prefer to use CSS, but if there is a JavaScript solution I'll use it

Comment: @theblindprophet I just need an image border partially covered by a panel

Comment: @TobySpeight Now is more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can really just get that *visual* effect without having to reorder layers etc. You can reverse the styles on those elements to get that appearance. Or you could do something even simpler like this:

```css
#main {
    position: relative;
    background: #e7e7e7;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 0 50px;
    margin: 50px;
}

#main::after {
    content: '';
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    top: -50px;
    background: #30353b;
}

#img-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    top: -20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
    <div id="main">
        <div id="img-container">
            <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/200">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. However using z-index seems to me as a more logical approach, isn't it?

Comment: As pointed out in other comments, it can be tricky though. It depends on various factors that don't necessarily play as you'd expect. As long as you're not trying to do too much with these elements, it's easy enough to style them so that they *appear* to be in reverse order, even when they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Question isn't clear, but are you just looking for something like this? (It basically involves replacing `margin-top` with `top` on the img-container.)

```css
#main {
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #e7e7e7;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 0 40px;
}
#img-container {
    top: -50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    background: #30373b;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 40px;
}
#img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="img-container">
        <img id="img" src="https://unsplash.it/400/200">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did.

Comment: But non what I wanted to do. Look at the order clause in the question.

Comment: All this question is about getting z-index to work as it have to work.